# Open .Parquet Files from AWS S3 in AWS SageMaker(jupyter notebook)

Tags: amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook, parquet, amazon-sagemaker

When I try to open .parquet files that I have in my AWS S3 using Jupyter Notebook, it says that Jupyter cant open it and its giving me an error. I'm wondering if it is incompatible or there is a workaround to it?

Answer (score 2):

what if you stage them to local disk first?
eg, if you want to do everything from jupyter (with [`pyarrow` installed](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/install.html))

1 first, in a markdown cell:

`! aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/file.parquet /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/`

2 then in a python cell in the same notebook:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

data = pq.read_table('file.parquet').to_pandas()
```